# How to insert CSS file below styles.css in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I can add a custom CSS file by adding this to `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`:

```
<head>
    <css src="css/local.css" />
</head>
```

However, it is still loaded before `/pub/media/styles.css` -- how do I get this file to load AFTER `styles.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `/pub/media/styles.css` is a file that contains only styles for the Luma homepage promo blocks, so if you have your own homepage design then you can safely remove it entirely by going to Admin / Stores / Configuration / General / Design / HTML Head and removing the link tag from the Miscellaneous Scripts field.

CSS files are not even supposed to be placed in the Miscellaneous Scripts field, as it's really meant for JavaScript files (you can tell by how `styles.css` is placed below the rest of the JS files). If you want to create a stylesheet that is only loaded on the homepage, then it's better to put your styles in a file called something like `home.css` and add it to only the homepage by overriding the `cms_index_index.xml` layout file.

Credit for locating `styles.css`: Gordova's answer to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99239/remove-pub-media-styles-css-from-theme-in-magento-2-0).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not possible with default functionality. You need to build a module for that behaviour.

I'm using this https://github.com/quickshiftin/mage2-ordered-assets module which works out of the box:

```
<css src=".." order="20"/>
```

Comment: I tried installing this module, and even though it does change the order of `local.css`, it is still loading before `/pub/media/styles.css` (the link tag immediately above `<meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />`). I realized I'm asking the wrong question -- the question I should be asking is how to remove `styles.css`. However, I will leave this question up for informational purposes.

Comment: It is in default support by Magento. You don't need this extension for it. this order tags works flawlessly without any module installation

Answer (score 0):

You can include all your code into the built in less functionality in the theme you have created. Make a file at:
`web/css/source/_extend.less` 
and place your css code there. You don't have to write less in these files, you can write vanilla css and will work just fine.

This file will be automatically and complied with the rest of the less files on the site and your code will be the last in the compilation process giving you [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The two files that get generated are `/pub/static/frontend/{{vender_name}}/{{your_theme}}/en_US/css/styles-l.css` and `/pub/static/frontend/{{vender_name}}/{{your_theme}}/en_US/css/styles-l.css`. These are the primary styles for the whole build. [More info about that process](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html)

For a decent work flow, you are going to have to pick the way that works best for you. If you are doing a lot of editing with a lot of css, you might want to get Grunt up and running. If you just have a little bit of work to do, `client side compilation` might be the best bet. [Read Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html) for more information on setting that up.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your solution is correct in that the CSS in `_extend.less` gets compiled into `styles-m.css`, however my current solution is already loading `local.css` after `styles-m.css`. I need a solution to load styles after `styles.css`, not `styles-m.css`.

Comment: style from web/css/source/_extend.less are paste to style-m.css but not style-l.css